# Maintenance Plugs

Tags: maintenance, electric-vehicle

I was going through the [FSAE International Rule-Book 2019](https://www.fsaeonline.com/cdsweb/gen/DownloadDocument.aspx?DocumentID=64b861c2-980a-40fc-aa88-6a80c43a8540) and encountered the term **Tractive System Accumulator Container – Maintenance Plugs** at section no. **EV.3.3**

I am actually a bit confused that what would the term **Maintenance Plugs** refer to? I guess it's not just some specific physical equipment but a general term, more like a category. When one reads the section, it reveals that somehow these plugs are allowing the electrical separations of the different segments of the EV's battery. But I don't exactly have a picture of its role in my mind.

If anyone can explain what these **Maintenance Plugs** are, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Make the effort to quote the passage9s) necessary instead of requiring us to download a document that we don't need.

Answer (score 1):

The linked document has interesting terminology.

I interpret the term "accumulator container" to refer to the battery, although I suspect use of this term allows for future development involving capacitors or Mr. Fusion devices.

There is mention of voltage specifications in the document.

Your understanding is correct, regarding electrical separations of the battery pack.

I had owned a 2003 Toyota Rav4EV which had a single plug just aft of the driver's seat, accessed via a hatch in the floor. When one opened the cover, a large handle was pulled, which completely disconnected the pack, approximately in the middle of the battery array.

The handle assembly meets the description in the document as being a device that cannot be bypassed or circumvented (not easily!) preventing activation of the battery pack. It also qualifies in that no tools are required to perform the disconnection. It also qualifies as the described physical device, no contactors, relays, etc.

If you consider the "old-time" movies of high voltage activation using a knife switch, the concept is similar.

[image: knife switch]

I did not read the link regarding voltage requirements, and it's possible that a half-pack split would not qualify for the document's restrictions.

Comment: "I interpret the term "accumulator container... " the document defines "Accumulator" as: EV.1.1.5 Accumulator - all the battery cells or super capacitors that store the electrical energy to be used by the Tractive System.